# Module definition for transient class in OpenXava

Tags: jpa, openxava

in the documentation of OX, is explained how to create a non-persisted class, obtaining just a view, with some actions/fields. Here is the link:

[View reference documentation](https://www.openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/view_en.html#:%7E:text=For%20defining%20a%20model%20class%20as%20transient%20you%20only%20need%20to%20define%20a%20regular%20Java%20class%20without%20%40Entity%20annotation)

Using version 6.6, I'm not able to configure a module in application.xml that makes this class work. Opening the module in the application leads always to a NullPointerException.

Here is one of my tentative. Can someone show me a working example?

```
<module name="TaxReturnControl">
    <view name="standard"/>
    <controller name="TaxReturnControl"/>       
    <mode-controller name="DetailOnly"/>
</module>
```

The controller definition is:

```
<controller name="TaxReturnControl">
    <extends controller="Print"/>
</controller>
```

The class definition is:

```
@Getter @Setter
@View(name="standard", members="taxReturnYear, taxPeriod")
public class TaxReturnControl {

  private Integer taxReturnYear = Integer.valueOf(0);

  private TaxPeriods taxPeriod = TaxPeriods.Q1;

  public enum TaxPeriods {Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4}
}
```

In the end, the last fragment of the console output:

```
> FINE: [JPATabProvider.nextBlock] Executing SELECT e.id, e.macsiCode, e.reasonCode.reasonCode, e_reasonCode.missingLinkedMacsi, e.isOpen, e.openingDate, e.closingDate from DataIssues e left join e.reasonCode e_reasonCode with arguments 
dic 04, 2021 1:55:48 PM org.openxava.tab.impl.TableModelBean getRow
FINE: nextChunk=838
dic 04, 2021 1:55:48 PM org.openxava.util.Labels getWithoutCache
WARNING: Impossible to translate element with id select
dic 04, 2021 1:55:48 PM org.openxava.util.Labels getWithoutCache
WARNING: Impossible to translate element with id Cards
dic 04, 2021 1:55:49 PM org.openxava.util.Labels getWithoutCache
WARNING: Impossible to translate element with id macsiCode
dic 04, 2021 1:55:49 PM org.openxava.util.Labels getWithoutCache
WARNING: Impossible to translate element with id reasonCode
dic 04, 2021 1:55:49 PM org.openxava.util.Labels getWithoutCache
WARNING: Impossible to translate element with id reasonCode
dic 04, 2021 1:55:49 PM org.openxava.util.Labels getWithoutCache
WARNING: Impossible to translate element with id missingLinkedMacsi
dic 04, 2021 1:55:49 PM org.openxava.util.Labels getWithoutCache
WARNING: Impossible to translate element with id isOpen
dic 04, 2021 1:55:49 PM org.openxava.util.Labels getWithoutCache
WARNING: Impossible to translate element with id openingDate
dic 04, 2021 1:55:49 PM org.openxava.util.Labels getWithoutCache
WARNING: Impossible to translate element with id closingDate
dic 04, 2021 1:55:49 PM org.openxava.web.dwr.DWRBase request
FINE: Request time=1918 ms
dic 04, 2021 1:55:53 PM org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager log
FINE: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 massimo MODULE:TaxReturnControl
dic 04, 2021 1:55:53 PM org.openxava.tab.Tab loadUserPreferences
WARNING: WARNING! Impossible to load tab preferences
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openxava.component.MetaComponent.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.tab.Tab.getMetaTab(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.tab.Tab.getPreferencesNodeName(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.tab.Tab.getPreferences(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.tab.Tab.loadUserPreferences(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.tab.Tab.setTabName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.xava.execute_jsp._jspService(execute_jsp.java:251)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:516)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:900)
    at org.apache.jsp.xava.module_jsp._jspService(module_jsp.java:294)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:516)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:900)
    at org.apache.jsp.naviox.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:264)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at com.openxava.naviox.web.NaviOXServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.openxava.naviox.web.NaviOXFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

dic 04, 2021 1:55:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openxava.view.View.getMetaModel(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.view.View.getMetaView(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.view.View.isFrame(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.xava.detail_jsp.openDiv(detail_jsp.java:54)
    at org.apache.jsp.xava.detail_jsp._jspService(detail_jsp.java:250)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:516)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:900)
    at org.apache.jsp.xava.core_jsp._jspService(core_jsp.java:325)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.openxava.web.servlets.Servlets.getURIAsString(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.web.servlets.Servlets.getURIAsString(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.web.dwr.Module.getURIAsString(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.web.dwr.Module.fillResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.web.dwr.Module.request(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.ExecuteAjaxFilter.doFilter(ExecuteAjaxFilter.java:34)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter$1.doFilter(DefaultRemoter.java:428)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:431)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:283)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.PlainCallHandler.handle(PlainCallHandler.java:52)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:101)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

dic 04, 2021 1:55:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openxava.view.View.getMetaModel(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.view.View.getMetaView(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.view.View.isFrame(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.xava.detail_jsp.openDiv(detail_jsp.java:54)
    at org.apache.jsp.xava.detail_jsp._jspService(detail_jsp.java:250)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:516)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:900)
    at org.apache.jsp.xava.core_jsp._jspService(core_jsp.java:325)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.openxava.web.servlets.Servlets.getURIAsString(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.web.servlets.Servlets.getURIAsString(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.web.dwr.Module.getURIAsString(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.web.dwr.Module.fillResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.web.dwr.Module.request(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.ExecuteAjaxFilter.doFilter(ExecuteAjaxFilter.java:34)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter$1.doFilter(DefaultRemoter.java:428)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:431)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:283)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.PlainCallHandler.handle(PlainCallHandler.java:52)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:101)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

dic 04, 2021 1:55:54 PM org.openxava.web.dwr.DWRBase request
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:638)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:514)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:516)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:900)
    at org.apache.jsp.xava.core_jsp._jspService(core_jsp.java:325)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.openxava.web.servlets.Servlets.getURIAsString(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.web.servlets.Servlets.getURIAsString(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.web.dwr.Module.getURIAsString(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.web.dwr.Module.fillResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.web.dwr.Module.request(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.ExecuteAjaxFilter.doFilter(ExecuteAjaxFilter.java:34)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter$1.doFilter(DefaultRemoter.java:428)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:431)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:283)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.PlainCallHandler.handle(PlainCallHandler.java:52)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:101)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openxava.view.View.getMetaModel(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.view.View.getMetaView(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxava.view.View.isFrame(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.xava.detail_jsp.openDiv(detail_jsp.java:54)
    at org.apache.jsp.xava.detail_jsp._jspService(detail_jsp.java:250)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    ... 64 more

dic 04, 2021 1:55:54 PM org.openxava.web.dwr.DWRBase request
FINE: Request time=240 ms
```

Comment: Please, add the stacktrace to your description. Define the module in your application.xml should be enough. You should change <controller name="Print"/> by <controller name="TaxReturnControl"/>. Also you should close <module> with </module>

Comment: Many thanks as usual Javier

Answer (score 0):

The model is missing in the module definition. Define your module in this way:

```
<module name="TaxReturnControl">
    <model name="TaxReturnControl"/>
    <view name="standard"/>
    <controller name="TaxReturnControl"/>       
</module>
```

Note the  tag to define the model. Also, mode-controller is not needed, since it's a transient property so the list mode is not available.